# Probabilities of Genetic Algorithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, stochastic-processes, expectation

Today, this crazy question came into my mind.

Let's consider the following optimization via Genetic Algorithm:

$$f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-0.5)^2+(x_2-0.5)^2$$

where

$$0\le x_1\le1 ~,~~~~~0\le x_2\le1$$

If I use GA with the following crossover and mutatoins,

crossover: $X_1=\{x_1^1,x_2^1\}, X_2=\{x_1^2,x_2^2\} \rightarrow X_{child}=rX_1+(1-r)X_2$

where $r$ are is a random number. (Here all random numbers are between 0 to 1 and distributed uniformly.)

mutation: $X_1=\{x_1^1,x_2^1\} \rightarrow X_{new}=\{x_1^1,r\}~~~ or~~~ X_{new}=\{r,x_2^1\}$ with 50%-50% chance

Crossover fraction is 0.7

Mutation fraction is 0.4

Elite count 4

Population 100

Selection: $1/\sqrt{n}$

Stop criteria: $f_{\min}^n-f_{\min}^{n-1}<10^{-6}$ for 5 generations

Then, the GA converges stops after N generations.

What is the expectation of N?

Is it possible to solve this problem analytically without statistics?

Another question is if I run GA for 50 generations, what will be the expected error (cost)?

Comment: what is wrong with the question? please explain.

Comment: The GA algorithm is a heuristic one, and a common rule of thumb about heuristic optimization algorithms is, don't look for analytic solutions or proofs. Even for the simplest cases it is almost impossible to find the $N$ analytically.